# Subtract 2 dates in visual basic Excel

Tags: excel, vba

As a result from a sql I've got a list of timestamps on each row.
For example:

2020-11-06 04:15:58.066993 in Cell A1

2020-11-06 11:35:41.319696 in Cell A2

I want to subtract those 2 dates (the result may be in hours and minutes, seconds and milliseconds are not needed). How can I do this in VBA?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```
Diff = CDate(CDate(Left(Cell2, 19)) - CDate(Left(Cell1, 19)))
```

The *Diff* will be a date/time value you can format as you like.

For a minute count:

```
Minutes = DateDiff("n", CDate(Left(Cell1, 19)), CDate(Left(Cell2, 19)))
```

Comment: That looks already good!
But some rows have a difference between the 2 timestamps that's for example 15 days. The outcome of the above function is then something like 15/01/1900 07:46:11. Is it possible to set the outcome for example only in minutes? Even if it exceeds more than 60 minutes. In this example the amount of minutes would be around 22066 minutes as difference.

Comment: Yes, you can use a function like [FormatHourMinute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214969/summing-up-hours-and-minutes-in-ms-access-how-to-deal-with-huge-datasets/39219790#39219790). For minutes only, see extended answer, please.